# .NET Process.Start default directory?

Tags: c#

I'm firing off a Java application from inside of a C# [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) console application. It works fine for the case where the Java application doesn't care what the "default" directory is, but fails for a Java application that only searches the current directory for support files.

Is there a process parameter that can be set to specify the default directory that a process is started in?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Yes!
ProcessStartInfo Has a property called *WorkingDirectory*, just use:

```
...
using System.Diagnostics;
...

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

  startInfo.WorkingDirectory = // working directory
  // set additional properties 

Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Can the `WorkingDirectory` be a relative path, and if so, what is it relative to, the current file or the directory of the current executable? I'm having trouble getting my program to find the executable I'm trying to start. I've set the working directory to the directory of the exe (relative to the current file and to the current exe), but it can't find it.

Answer (score 66):

Use the [*ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) property to set it prior to starting the process.  If the property is not set, the default working directory is %SYSTEMROOT%\system32.

You can determine the value of %SYSTEMROOT% by using:

```
string _systemRoot = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SYSTEMROOT");
```

Here is some sample code that opens Notepad.exe with a working directory of %ProgramFiles%:

```
...
using System.Diagnostics;
...

ProcessStartInfo _processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
  _processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"%ProgramFiles%";
  _processStartInfo.FileName         = @"Notepad.exe";
  _processStartInfo.Arguments        = "test.txt";
  _processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow   = true;
Process myProcess = Process.Start(_processStartInfo);
```

There is also an Environment variable that controls the current working directory for your process that you can access directly through the [*Environment.CurrentDirectory*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx) property .

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could use environment variables in the .WorkingDirectory property.

Comment: Bingo, that's the answer -- the default directory is SYSTEMROOT. +1

Answer (score 30):

Just a note after hitting my head trying to implement this.
Setting the WorkingDirectory value does not work if you have "UseShellExecute" set to false.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Even 6 years later, this comment about UseShellExecute was helpful. Fixed the issue.

Answer (score 11):

Use the ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory property.

Docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

The Process.Start method has an overload that takes an instance of ProcessStartInfo. This class has a property called "WorkingDirectory".

Set that property to the folder you want to use and that should make it start up in the correct folder.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `ProcessStartInfo` class and assign a value to the `WorkingDirectory` property.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a catch 22 like @cbbspike as I wanted to have both `UseShellExecute` equal to `false` and set the  `WorkingDirectory` to where the EXE should start. So I took @larry-smithmier answer and set the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` as he suggested.

Note: I did **not** have to surround the directory in quotes. In my case the `scriptsPath` variable was the directory `C:\Program Files\SomeDir\`

```cs
Environment.CurrentDirectory = scriptsPath;

ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell.exe", scriptArguments);
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
//processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = // intended working directory
```