# C# equivalent of cd C:\appFolder c:\app.exe?

Tags: c#, batch-file, process.start

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.Net Process.Start default directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114928/net-process-start-default-directory)

I have a C# application, mono to be specific. This application needs to launch another application on the users system. I know of Process.Start and how to use it, but theres something pecuilar about this instance which makes that not work correctly.

For some reason the program I am trying to launch via Process.Start needs to be called from the directory it resides in, otherwise it gives an error on opening.

What I mean by that is, if I open up a command prompt and type in:
C:\appFolder\app.exe
The application will then give me an error.

However if I open a prompt and go:
cd c:\appFolder
app.exe

It then launches just fine.

The problem I am having with process.start is it tries to open the application without first doing what is the equivalent of 'cd c:\appFolder', and so the application gives an error on opening.

So how can I do make Process.Start do what would be the equivalent of first navigating to the apps folder 'cd c:\appFolder' and then calling app.exe?

BTW, I have solved this problem by putting
cd C:\appFolder
app.exe

into a .bat file, and have Process.Start open the .bat file, which works just fine. But I am curious to know if there is a way to cut out the .bat file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `cd blah` just changes your working directory. You can set the working directory of your process by setting the `WorkingDirectory` of your `ProcessStartInfo`. Perhaps something like this:

```
var procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("app.exe");
procInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\appFolder";
Process.Start(procInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing the working directory before your call

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"path");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx

Comment: A possible downside to this approach is that it will change the working directory for the *current* program as well; not just the spawned process.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("app.exe");
        psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\appFolder";
        Process.Start(psi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) object to start the application and set the `WorkingDirectory` property accordingly.