# Alternatives to System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

Tags: c#, process.start

For some unknown reasons, An Executable (iw4sp.exe executable for Call of duty modern warfare 2) runs normally when launched from explorer but crashes when launched by Process.Start() in my application. Any alternatives to Process.Start?? i tried starting explorer by passing iw4sp as argument, but same thing happens. Application exited with a code that a file was missing (i double checked that file exists.) same error was faced when i created . *.url shortcut to exe and ran from explorer.

Comment: does the properties of the shortcut have any start in directory?

Comment: Can you show us your code?  Also, try setting the working directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114928/net-process-start-default-directory

Answer (score 4):

Create a  `ProcessStartInfo`, set its `WorkingDirectory` and use `Process.Start(processStartInfo);`

Answer (score 2):

No alternative to `process.start` but an alternative to your code

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe","iw4sp.exe");
```