# How to run remote bat file without prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, permissions, file-permissions

I have a remote drive mapped to my local Z:\ drive.

When running using this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Z:\\Test.bat");
```

It opens a prompt as to whether or not to open the file.  How do I disable this setting in windows or get around it using c#?

Comment: One possible reason is a Windows security setting which prevents execution of batch files with a directory on a network drive as current working directory. The solution is to set a local directory as working directory before starting the batch file as explained at [.NET Process.Start default directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/114928/3074564)

Comment: And a second possible reason is that the server with the public share mapped as drive Z: does not belong to the trusted sites of local intranet. See on Super User [How to get rid of “the publisher cannot be verified” on network files?](http://superuser.com/a/381592)