# Path to Console Application called from another console aplication

Tags: c#

How to call console application from FirstConsolApplication project, in SecondConsolApplication project? Everything is in same solution

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Process p = new Process())
            {
                p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = @"SecondConsolApplication.exe",
                    Arguments = "OneArgument",
                };
                p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                using (ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false))
                {
                    p.Exited += (s, e) => mre.Set();
                    p.Start(); //ERROR IS HERE !
                    mre.WaitOne();
                }

                Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
```

I get exception:

> The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: That path format requires the second executable to be in the working directory of the first one. Where _are_ both executables, relative to each other?

Comment: I want that FirstConsolApplication work, after any change in SecondConsolApplication. I don't want to copy paste second executable to working directory of first project every time I change something.

Comment: **Where is** the second executable? It can be as simple as using `..\SecondProject\bin\Debug\SecondExecutable.exe`. Basic path logic.

Comment: `FileName` give the Full path of the `exe` it will work..

Comment: @CodeCaster Can't be add as using, it is .exe (not .dll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the full path to the `.exe` file or have to set the [`workingDirectory`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114928/net-process-start-default-directory).

Comment: Ok, thanks, it's working. But how to add relative path to .exe file in another project?