# Dependency file could not be loaded when opening .exe file using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a program named `C:\\AAA\\AAA.exe`, and the program is running well. Now if I try to open the `.exe` file, like this:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\\AAA\\AAA.exe")
```

it doesn't work. The problem is, the dependency file from `AAA.exe` (dependency is an `.Lwg` file, say, `abc.lwg`) could not opened.

Can someone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: You probably need to set the working directory for the process.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to set working directory to,

```
C:\\AAA\\
```

Assuming .Lwg file lives there

[see how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114928/net-process-start-default-directory).