# Execute .jar from windows form C#

Tags: java, c#, forms, winforms, jar

I have .jar to execute from windows from, so far I was able to lunch the program from my window form, but when I put information in my java file I get no result the java file does nothing.
If I go manualy double click and execute the .jar file and put the information I get the resul.

here is my code to execute java inside windows form :

```
 Process p = Process.Start(@"C:\convert\Convert.jar");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            p.WaitForInputIdle();
            SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
```

.jar file is for to convert .csv to .txt with special data.

Comment: `java -jar C:\convert\Convert.jar`

Comment: Thanks Liberty but it is not working I have tried this before.

Comment: @nater303 what exactly happens when you run LibertyLocked's suggestion? It's definitely more correct than the original attempt. For testing purposes: try running ``java -version``.

Comment: I can execute the .jar file but no result for my conversion.

Comment: And for java version :

java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

NOTE: csv.csv it is in the same folder as Convert.jar

Comment: @nater303 Have you tried setting working directory to C:\convert? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114928/net-process-start-default-directory

Comment: BINGO!
It woks, I had to set up the working directory because the .jar looks for files in the same folder where it is.
Thanks Liberty Locked for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
System.Diagnostics; ... ProcessStartInfo _processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
_processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"%ProgramFiles%";
_processStartInfo.FileName = @"Notepad.exe"; 
_processStartInfo.Arguments = "test.txt"; 
_processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process myProcess = Process.Start(_processStartInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

To run a jar, you need to use

```
java -jar <FILENAME.jar>
```

In your case it would be

```
Process p = Process.Start(@"java -jar C:\convert\Convert.jar");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
```