# Jar file classpath problems

Tags: java, c#, jar

I am developing a C# application wich have access to console to run the java command and execute an specific jar, but when I run the program, the executing jar file generate his files on program output, like logs and configuration, but I want to run the jar that's already in a specific folder with his files
The problem is that I tried many java arguments, but the generated output files from the jar goes everytime to my Debug folder from my visual studio project
Hope anyone understood me, I very confused and sorry for my english, I am brazillian
For now, thanks for your support!

Comment: You should set the current working directory to what the invoked program expects before invoking it.

Comment: yes I just think about it, but how I set the working directory for the jar? I tried with -cp argument but no result

Comment: You must do this in the surrounding environment where you invoke the java command.

Comment: please help I am getting crazy with this, I can't modify the jar file, it's pre-compiled and is not my project, I only invoke it from my C# application, what to do? :(

Comment: Please show the code you are using to launch the java application from C#  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess, because the lines of code are missing that you use to invoke the java program from within your C# program. It is also unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. Decide between changing the "current work directory" in the child or in the main process.

## child process

I assume you want to execute something like this `java -jar path\to\some.jar` using code similar to this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
//...

ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
p.Arguments = new string[]{"-jar", "path\to\some.jar"; 
p.FileName = "java.exe";
p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.CreateNoWindow = true;

using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
{
     proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

*Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/240610/3165552)*

Then you can just add this line

```
p.WorkingDirectory = "path\to";
```

*Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114937/3165552)*

to setup your child process covered by the `p` instance with a specific current work directory. This will set the current work directory for the invocation of your `java` child process.

## main process

To setup the current work directory for the surrounding main process add this line to your program:

```
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("some\other\path");
```

*MSDN Documentation for [`SetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)*