# .EXE does not start with Process.Start(path_to.exe)

Tags: c#, inno-setup, process.start

I have created `DatePicker.exe` with Inno Setup.

```
Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyJournal

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        8/17/2017   4:44 AM                Log
-a----        8/17/2017   3:30 PM           2747 appointments.bin
-a----        8/17/2017   1:46 PM          45056 DatePicker.exe
-a----         8/8/2017   8:35 AM            189 DatePicker.exe.config
-a----        8/17/2017   1:46 PM          79360 DatePicker.pdb
-a----        8/15/2017  10:17 AM           1122 DatePicker.SED
-a----        8/17/2017   1:47 PM          12946 unins000.dat
-a----        8/17/2017   1:47 PM         725157 unins000.exe
```

This does not work - `DatePicker.exe` does not open, and there are no errors:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyJournal\DatePicker.exe");
```

But this works

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\MyJournal.lnk");
```

Link from desktop points to the same path as above.

Why does the first example not work?

UPDATE.

As suggested I have tried to set the working directory.
But no luck so far. This did not work for me.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files(x86)\MyJournal";
startInfo.FileName = @"DatePicker.exe";
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process myProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

**UPDATE # 2**;

```
It finally works with
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyJournal\DatePicker.exe");
                psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyJournal";
                Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: Have you tried `Process.Start(@"C:\PROGRA~2\MyJournal\DatePicker.exe");`?

Comment: Is there a working folder set on that shortcut? Is the program crashing immediately upon starting?

Comment: If you put a copy of DatePicker.exe on your Desktop, and try to run it while it is on your Desktop, does it work?

Comment: I think the problem is with spaces.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov, just tried your suggestion, it's not working for me.

Comment: @ 0liveradam8, I had tried; it is not working.  Process.Start(@"C:\Users\nagel\Desktop\DatePicker.exe");

Comment: What happens when you manually open `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyJournal\DatePicker.exe` ?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov, It works fine when opened manually.

Comment: You should modify your application to use application-relative paths (which are absolute paths using your application's location as the base) rather than purely-relative paths to dependent files.  Then the working folder won't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible it's not running because the default directory is not set? Try using a [StartInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114928/net-process-start-default-directory) parameter instead, and set the working directory to the same as the program directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting it from the Command Promt? If the application is working fine when manually opening it, it may be because of `UseShellExecute` begin **true** by default.

Try `startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;`

According to MSDN `startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;` is ignored when `UseShellExecute` is **true** or if the `UserName` and `Password` properties are not **null**.