# C# executing an exe file as if it were from the exe's own folder

Tags: c#

I need to mimic the command line version of this:

If i am in say `H:\`

And run:

```
H:\> D:\MyFolder\MyOtherFolder\TheFile.exe
```

This will launch TheFile.exe app, though that needs to run as if it was launched from:

```
D:\MyFolder\MyOtherFolder\> TheFile.exe
```

Anyway to get Process.Launch to execute from actual folder not the app folder thats running the code that launches the .exe?

Comment: Setting the current directory should mimic some  of the effects https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114928/net-process-start-default-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the working directory in Process start. For example:

```
   AppProcess = new Process();

   AppProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\\MyFolder\\MyOtherFolder\\TheFile.exe";
   AppProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "D:\\MyFolder\\MyOtherFolder";
   AppProcess.Start();
```