# How to execute multiple commands to open application in Process.Start() that opens cmd.exe in single process using command-line?

Tags: vb.net, command-line, cmd, process

I can't change directory from `C:\` to `C:\Apps\app.exe` in single execution. Cmd doesn't allow me to do it. I want to execute `C:\Apps` first then, execute `app.exe`argument in order to open `app.exe` using `Process.Start()` that opens `cmd.exe` in a single run. Here is my code.

```
Dim FullPath As String = "C:\Apps\app.exe"
Dim appPath As String = "C:\Apps"
Dim appName As String = "app.exe"
Dim p As Process = Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k cd " + appPath)
'Don't know what to do here...
```

My output should be like this:
[image: Cmd]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Process.Start default directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114928/net-process-start-default-directory)

Comment: Very helpful link. It helps me to solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Babbillumpa i've solved my problem:

```
Dim _processStartInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
        _processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = appPath
        _processStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        _processStartInfo.Arguments = "/k app.exe"
        _processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

        Dim myProcess As Process = Process.Start(_processStartInfo)
        'wait for specific time for the thread to be closed
        myProcess.WaitForExit(500)

        ' Close process by sending a close message to its main window.
        myProcess.CloseMainWindow()
        ' Free resources associated with process.
        myProcess.Close()
```