# pyinstaller .exe works locally but fails when called by C#?

Tags: c#, python, executable, pyinstaller

I have created a script using Python2.7 and compiled it using pyinstaller into an exe of the same name, in this case "GeneralStats.py" turns into "GeneralStats.exe" using --onefile and -w arguments.

When called with C# I use:

```
var pythonDirectory = (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
var filePathExe1 = Path.Combine(pythonDirectory + "\\Python\\GeneralStats.exe");
Process.Start(filePathExe1);
```

When called outside of C#, so in my local files I can run the .exe and the result is a text file with lots of values in (Running correctly).

However, when ran with C# in this format, I get an error that "GeneralStats returned -1!"

Which I have had issues with before, but it was a simple python error that when I returned to my code and ran it, I would receive an error that I overlooked. 
This time my python code returns no errors and works outside of C#.

Any ideas of why this could be? I can provide any code or file directories necessary, please just ask if you feel it would help with debugging.

EDIT:

Solved by removing:

```
var filePathExe1 = Path.Combine(pythonDirectory + "\\Python\\GeneralStats.exe");
Process.Start(filePathExe1);
```

And replacing with:

```
ProcessStartInfo _processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
_processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(pythonDirectory + "\\Python");
_processStartInfo.FileName = @"GeneralStats.exe";
_processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process myProcess = Process.Start(_processStartInfo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the working directory for the `Process` - it is probably trying to load files from its working directory but isn't finding them.

See, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/115287/1364007):

> Use the [`ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_WorkingDirectory) property to set it prior to starting the process. If the property is not set, the default working directory is `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32`.

Set it to the path where `GeneralStats.exe` is.