# Run PyInstaller Exe File with C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, pyinstaller, executable

I've written my code in Python 3.6 and got the exe file using PyInstaller. My exe needs some files to run (like txt files to read the lines). When I put the exe file and the other files in same folder, exe file works perfectly.

But when I want to run the exe file with C#, it says that it can't find the other files even they are in same folder.

As I searched on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164715/pyinstaller-exe-works-locally-but-fails-when-called-by-c); I used this C# code;

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace RunExeFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo _processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            _processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Users\\wicaledon\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Test\\";
            _processStartInfo.FileName = @"Statistics.exe";
            _processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Process myProcess = Process.Start(_processStartInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

But it didn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: @mjwills They are in `"C:\Users\wicaledon\OneDrive\Desktop\Test\"` folder. It doesn't work if I comment out `CreateNoWindow` line. This is .NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest setting `UseShellExecute` to `true`.

This is because setting `WorkingDirectory` has different [behaviour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netframework-4.8) depending on the value of `UseShellExecute`:

> When the UseShellExecute property is false, gets or sets the working
>   directory for the process to be started. When UseShellExecute is true,
>   gets or sets the directory that contains the process to be started.

Comment: I have a question to you. I used these lines and it works on Windows10 perfectly. But there is problem in Windows7. Should we change some lines? Or the problem is  from mine somewhere?